# Show that a curve is planar (and not planar)

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $\gamma(t)$ be defined as follows:

$$\gamma(t)=(\cos t,\sin t,\cos t)$$

I was able to show that $\gamma$ is regular by supposing that it is planar, then finding $\vec n$ such that $\vec n\cdot\gamma=0$. $\vec n=(1,0,-1)$ is a reasonable choice.

Would using the binormal vector result in a similar answer? I attempted to do it but I'm not totally sure I'm on the right track, because the calculations got really difficult and I atributted it to mistakes in my calculations.

Also, how would I show that $\omega(t)$, defined as follows:

$$\omega(t)=(\cos t,\sin t,\cos 2t)$$

is not planar? Finding a vector which results in having a dot product zero seems easy, but proving it does not exist for a curve like this seems much harder.

Comment: Have you considered computing the torsion? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torsion_of_a_curve

Comment: Calculating the binormal vector to any of these curves seems to be really hard, so calculating the torsion is probably going to be even harder. Also, I have not talked about torsion in class. There must be something about the binormal vector I'm missing, because I don't remember it being this hard to calculate

Comment: By the way, if the curve is planar, then am I right in thinking that $r'$ and $r''$ must always lie with a given plane? i.e. the direction of $r' \times r''$ is the same at all times?

Comment: A third suggestion: find four points on the curve and show they don't lie in a plane!